# Make all fields required in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Mongoose seems to default to make all fields not required. Is there any way to make all the fields required without changing each of:

```
Dimension = mongoose.Schema(
  name: String
  value: String
)
```

to

```
Dimension = mongoose.Schema(
  name:
    type: String
    required: true
  value: 
    type: String
    required: true
)
```

It'll get really ugly since I have a lot of these.

Comment: If all fields are required, why are you using a schema-less database?

Comment: A schema-less database has nothing to do with required fields, you can use non-required fields in a relational database and vice versa. (in my opinion)

Comment: I feel that this should be a part of the api. That is, passing this as an option to the constructor when building the Schema. Strange it doesn't exist and solutions offered to aggregate them are quite ugy. Probably the cleanest way to do this is by wrapping mongoose.Schema with a decorator and building this constructor yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
r_string = 
  type: String
  required: true 

r_number = 
  type: Number
  required: true
```

and on for the other data types.

Comment: Where did you end up placing this ? @maxko87

Answer (score 12):

You could do something like:

```
var schema = {
  name: { type: String},
  value: { type: String}
};

var requiredAttrs = ['name', 'value'];

for (attr in requiredAttrs) { schema[attr].required = true; }

var Dimension = mongoose.schema(schema);
```

or for all attrs (using underscore, which is awesome):

```
var schema = {
  name: { type: String},
  value: { type: String}
};

_.each(_.keys(schema), function (attr) { schema[attr].required = true; });

var Dimension = mongoose.schema(schema);
```

Comment: And the implicit declaration of the required attributes is only slipping the problem aside and making it even uglier.

Answer (score 9):

All fields properties are in `schema.paths[attribute]` or `schema.path(attribute)`;

One proper way to go : define when a field is NOT required,

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Myschema = new Schema({
    name : { type:String },
    type : { type:String, required:false }
})
```

and make them all required by default :

```
function AllFieldsRequiredByDefautlt(schema) {
    for (var i in schema.paths) {
        var attribute = schema.paths[i]
        if (attribute.isRequired == undefined) {
            attribute.required(true);
        }
    }
}

AllFieldsRequiredByDefautlt(Myschema)
```

The underscore way :

```
_=require('underscore')
_.each(_.keys(schema.paths), function (attr) {
    if (schema.path(attr).isRequired == undefined) {
        schema.path(attr).required(true);
    }
})
```

Test it :

```
MyTable = mongoose.model('Myschema', Myschema);
t = new MyTable()
t.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you could write a mongoose schema plugin function that walked the schema object and adjusted it to make each field required. Then you'd just need 1 line per schema: `Dimension.plugin(allRequired)`.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose didn't provide the method of setting all fields, but you could do it recursively.

Like Peter mentioned, you could pluginize it in order to reuse the code.

**Recursively setting:**

```
// game.model.js
var fields = require('./fields');
var Game = new Schema({ ... });

for(var p in Game.paths){
  Game.path(p).required(true);
}
```

**Pluginized:**

```js
// fields.js
module.exports = function (schema, options) {
  if (options && options.required) {
    for(var p in schema.paths){
      schema.path(p).required(true);
    }
  }
}

// game.model.js
var fields = require('./fields');
var Game = new Schema({ ... });
Game.plugin(fields, { required: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do it in Mongoose, but I would do the following in your IDE/editor:

List out your fields as you would normally:

```
Dimension = mongoose.Schema(
  name: String
  value: String
)
```

Then do a find and replace on `String` and replace it with `{type: String, required: true},` Giving you:

```
Dimension = mongoose.Schema(
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  value:  {type: String, required: true},
)
```

Then do the same for `Number` and other types.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answers, the module below will make fields required by default. The previous answers did not recurse nested objects/arrays.

Usage:

```
const rSchema = require("rschema");

var mySchema = new rSchema({
    request:{
        key:String,
        value:String
    },
    responses:[{
        key:String,
        value:String
    }]
});
```

Node module:

```
const Schema = require("mongoose").Schema;

//Extends Mongoose Schema to require all fields by default
module.exports = function(data){
    //Recursive
    var makeRequired = function(schema){
        for (var i in schema.paths) {
            var attribute = schema.paths[i];
            if (attribute.isRequired == undefined) {
                attribute.required(true);
            }
            if (attribute.schema){
                makeRequired(attribute.schema);
            }
        }
    };

    var schema = new Schema(data);
    makeRequired(schema);
    return schema;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this function for the complex types you may have so you don't have to declare a new variable for each type you have.

```js
function require<T>(type: T): { type: T; required: true } {
  return {
    type,
    required: true,
  };
}
```

To use it you will just do this:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  someRequiredField: require(String),
  someCustomTypedField: require(MyType),
});
```

It's much more cleaner and also more self explanatory this way.